# Reorder a nodelist in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, sorting

I would like to sort my nodelist by the VM field Name attribute.
The xml:

```
 <SRM>
  <HBR>
    <VM Name="mast0010">
      <FieldOne>ttttt</FieldOne>
      <Disk Name="Name One">
        <FieldTwo>aaaaa</FieldTwo>
        <FieldThree>bbbbb</FieldThree>
      </Disk>
      <Disk Name="Name Two">
        <FieldTwo>fffff</FieldTwo>
        <FieldThree>ccccc</FieldThree>
      </Disk>
    </VM>
    <VM Name="mast0003">
      <FieldOne>rrrrr</FieldOne>
      <Disk Name="Name One">
        <FieldTwo>ddddd</FieldTwo>
        <FieldThree>eeeee</FieldThree>
      </Disk>
    </VM>
  </HBR>
</SRM>
```

I wrote the code below:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("VM");        
var ax = Array.prototype.slice.call(x, 0);

for (var i=0; i<ax.length; i++) {
ax.sort(function(a, b){
    var a = ax[i].getAttribute('Name');
    var b = ax[i].getAttribute('Name');
    if(a < b) return -1;
    if(a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
    });
}

for (i=0; i<ax.length; i++) {
    document.write(ax[i].getAttribute('Name') + "<br/>");
}
```

It returns mast0010, mast0003
I would need mast0003,mast0010 order. Please help me out. I don't unerstand where the problem is.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `document.write`, it's from an ancient version of JavaScript and not meant to be used anymore. If you want to add nodes into an active document, use DOM manipulation functions like [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), etc.

You're also calling ax.sort a million times (or rather, once for every element in the array). That's not how you use sort, so just turn that into a single line, and rely on the sort inputs, don't reach out to your array.

Rewritten code:

```
ax = ax.sort(function(a,b) {
  a = a.getAttribute("Name");
  b = b.getAttribute("Name");
  return a < b ? -1 : b < a ? 1 : 0; });
});
```

and then insert the resulting elements into the document the proper way.

```
ax.forEach(function(node) {
  document.body.appendChild(node);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[**Check this working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eZZV/1/)

Here is the sorting function fixed for you.

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("HBR")[0].getElementsByTagName("VM");        
var ax = Array.prototype.slice.call(x, 0);

for (var i=0; i<ax.length; i++) {
ax.sort(function(a, b){
    a = a.getAttribute('Name');
    b = b.getAttribute('Name');

    if(a < b) return -1;
    if(a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: you can compare strings with < and > just fine, it does the correct thing based on standard string comparison rules.

Comment: though this still relies on parseInt, which isn't necessary at all here =)